# How to accept an array of key:value arguments in a Thor generator command?

Tags: ruby, thor

I am working on creating a generator similar to the Rails scaffolding generator. I would like to accept an array of `key:value` arguments. Like this:

```
mycli generate model BlogPost title:string body:text published:datetime
```

Currently my command class looks something like this:

```
require "thor"

module Mycli
  module Generators
    class Model < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions

      argument :model_name
      # argument :model_attributes # TODO: figure out how to get array of attributes

      def self.source_root
        File.dirname(__FILE__)
      end

      def generate_model
        template('templates/model.tt', "app/models/#{model_name}.rb")
      end

      def generate_migration
        template('templates/migration.tt', "migrations/#{model_name}.rb")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What do I need to do in order to access that list of attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this feature is already supported. You just need to specify the argument type as a `:hash`.

```
argument :model_attributes, optional: true, type: :hash
```